# Django Dynamic Formset UpdateView Not Updating

Tags: python, django, dynamic, formset

I used [this](https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6) tutorial to successfully set up a dynamic inline formset using Django. The CreateView works great, but I cannot get the UpdateView to actually update the related fields. There are no errors thrown, but the items will not update. I believe I have isolated the error to the form_valid function. The code is as follows. Thank you for any assistance.

```
class ApplicantCreate(CreateView):
    model = Applicant
    success_message = 'Your application was submitted successfully.'
    form_class = forms.ApplicantForm
    template_name = 'careers/add_applicant.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('careers:thanks')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ApplicantCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        positions = super(ApplicantCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['employer'] = forms.ApplicantEmployerFormSet(
                                    self.request.POST,
                                    prefix='employer')
            data['education'] = forms.ApplicantEducationFormSet(
                                     self.request.POST,
                                     prefix='education')
        else:
            data['employer'] = forms.ApplicantEmployerFormSet(prefix='employer')
            data['education'] = forms.ApplicantEducationFormSet(prefix='education')
        return data
        context['unfilled_positions'] = Position.objects.filter(filled=False)
        return positions

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        employer = context['employer']
        education = context['education']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            if employer.is_valid():
                employer.instance = self.object
                employer.save()
            if education.is_valid():
                education.instance = self.object
                education.save()
        return super(ApplicantCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('careers:thanks')

class ApplicantUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,GroupRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    group_required = [u'careers-admin',u'careers']
    model = Applicant
    success_message = '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s was updated successfully.'
    form_class = forms.ApplicantUpdateForm
    template_name = 'careers/edit_applicant.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ApplicantUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        positions = super(ApplicantUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['employer'] = forms.ApplicantEmployerFormSet(
                                    self.request.POST,
                                    instance=self.object,
                                    prefix='employer')
            data['education'] = forms.ApplicantEducationFormSet(
                                    self.request.POST,
                                    instance=self.object,
                                    prefix='education')
        else:
            data['employer'] = forms.ApplicantEmployerFormSet(
                                    instance=self.object,
                                    prefix='employer')
            data['education'] = forms.ApplicantEducationFormSet(
                                    instance=self.object,
                                    prefix='education')
        return data
        context['unfilled_positions'] = Position.objects.filter(filled=False)
        return positions

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        employer = context['employer']
        education = context['education']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            if employer.is_valid():
                employer.instance = self.object
                employer.save()
            if education.is_valid():
                education.instance = self.object
                education.save()
        return super(ApplicantUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('careers:applicant_detail',kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: This is not a good approach, since you don't do anything if the formset isn't valid (no errors are thrown).

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your `form_valid()` method to inspect `employer` and `education` (e.g. `employer.errors`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good blog post, because no errors are shown if any of the inline forms aren't valid. As a user, I wouldn't expect the view to just silently ignore errors in the inline forms, saving my main instance successfully and not reporting back those errors.

Note that I don't know what the errors are, maybe it's just an issue with the management form. But in any case, formset errors should be handled **before** the main object is actually saved.

In general, if you need to write a view with multiple forms (including a formset), it's better to use a function-based view or a `View` where you write the `get` and `post` than trying to force this into a generic class-based view, which is not meant for this.

```
def multiple_forms_view(request, object_id):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=object_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, instance=obj, ...)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = MyForm(instance=obj)
        formset = MyFormSet(instance=obj, ...)

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

That way your template can render the errors of each form, including those in the formset. As mentioned before, you could also do this in a `View` (so your mixins will work), just write the `get` and `post` methods and return the same as in the function-based view above.